# WinSCP Session::RemoveFiles - Delete specified files in sub directories

Tags: file-io, winscp, winscp-net

[Question] Does `Session::RemoveFiles()` remove files in sub directory of source directory? If not, how to implement this ability?

(Please do not ask me why I have the remote directory as `/C/testTransfer/`. The code just for testing purpose.)

I have a SFTP program using WinSCP .Net assembly. Program language is C++/CLI. It opens up a work file. The file contains many lines of FTP instructions.

One type of instruction I have to handle is to transfer `*.txt` from source directory. The source directory may contain sub directories which may contain `.txt` as well. Once transfer is successful, delete the source files.

I use `Session::GetFiles()` for the transfer. It correctly transfer all `.txt` files (`/C/testTransfer/*.txt`), even those in sub directories (`/C/testTransfer/sub/*.txt`), in the source to the destination.

```c
transferOptions->FileMask = "*.txt";
session->GetFiles("/C/testTransfer", "C:\\temp\\win", false, transferOption);
```

Now to remove, I use `session->RemoveFiles("/C/testTransfer/*.txt")`. I only see `*.txt` in the source (`/C/testTransfer/*.txt`), but not in the sub directory (`/C/testTransfer/sub/*.txt`), are removed.

Answer (score 2):

The [`Session::RemoveFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_removefiles) can remove even files in subdirectories in general. But not this way with wildcard, because WinSCP will not descend to subdirectories that do not match the wildcard (`*.txt`). Also note that even if you do not need the wildcard, the `Session::RemoveFiles` would remove even the subdirectories themselves, what I'm not sure you want it to.

Though you have other (and better = more safe) options:

- Use the [`remove` parameter](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles#remove) of the [`Session::GetFiles` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles) to instruct it to remove source file after **successful** transfer.
- If you need to delete source files transactionally (=only after download of all files succeed), iterate the [`TransferOperationResult::Transfers`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_transferoperationresult) returned by `Session::GetFiles` and call the `Session::RemoveFiles` for each (unless the `TransferEventArgs::Error` is not null).

  Use the `TransferEventArgs::FileName` to get a file path to pass to the `Session::RemoveFiles`. Use the [`RemotePath::EscapeFileMask`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_remotepath_escapefilemask) to escape the file name before passing it to the `Session::RemoveFiles`.

  There's a similar full example available for [Moving local files to different location after successful upload](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_local_move_after_successful_upload).
- To recursively delete files matching a wildcard in a standalone operation (not after downloading the same files), use the [`Session::EnumerateRemoteFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_enumerateremotefiles). Pass your wildcard to its `mask` argument. Use the `EnumerationOptions.AllDirectories` option for recursion.

  Call the `Session::RemoveFiles` for each returned file. Use the [`RemotePath::EscapeFileMask`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_remotepath_escapefilemask) to escape the file name before passing it to the `Session::RemoveFiles`.